# Does Covenant affect NPC invaders?

Tags: dark-souls-2

There are some we know the answer for already, like the Mad Warrior will only spawn if you're a part of the Bell Covenant. But are there any others?

For example, will the (offline invader) Bell Keeper still spawn if you're a part of the Bell Keeper's? Or will (offline invader) Rhoy the Explorer spawn if you're a part of the Rat King Covenant?

Comment: I do not know about the bell keepers, but i can confirm that Rhoy won't spawn if you are in the rat covenant:
http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/rhoy-the-explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

There are several invaders that will/won't spawn, depending on whether or not you're in a specific covenant.

- [Rhoy the Explorer](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Rhoy+the+Explorer) **will not** spawn if you are a part of the Rat King Covenant.
- [Bowman Guthry](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Bowman+Guthry) **will not** spawn if you are a part of the Rat King Covenant

These two only invade offline, and you will get a message "Dark spirit [name] has invaded!"

There is one other phantom that will only appear if you are online:

- [The Mad Warrior](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Mad+Warrior) **will only** spawn if you are in the Bellkeepers Covenant.

Additionally, he *will* spawn multiple times, and will *not* have a scripted entrance. He spawns randomly in Belfry Sol, so if he does not appear, go back and rest at the bonfire.